# Are all the forms of Vishnu 4 handed?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, bhagavata-purana

> 1. The original spiritual planet which resembles the whorl of the huge Lotus flower, is called Goloka Vrindavana.It is the abode of Lord Krishna, the original personality of Godhead.
> 2. This original planet Goloka throws off a spiritual ray of effulgence called Brahmajyoti which is the ultimate goal of the impersonalits.
> 3. Within this unlimited Brahmajyoti, there are unlimited planets. These spiritual planets belong to expansions of Lord Krishna and all of them are **4 handed**

Are all the forms of Vishnu Chaturbhuja? Are there any of this incarnations in which he is seen 10 handed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lord Vishnu as he originally is in his abode is 4 handed. However he adopts different forms which are not all four handed. I will describe a few of his non-for handed forms.

The eight armed form in which he appeared before Daksha Prajapati:

> O Mahārāja Parīkṣit, best of the Kuru dynasty, the Lord’s lotus feet rested on the shoulders of His carrier, Garuḍa, and **He appeared with eight long, mighty, very beautiful arms. In His hands He held a disc, conchshell, sword, shield, arrow, bow, rope and club** — in each hand a different weapon, all brilliantly shining. His garments were yellow and His bodily hue deep bluish.
> -*Srimad Bhagavatam 6.4.35*

The thousand handed form that stood on the summit of the Mandara mountain during the Samudra Manthana:

> Manifesting Himself **with a thousand hands**, the Lord then appeared on the summit of Mandara Mountain, like another great mountain, and held Mandara Mountain with one hand.
> - *Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.12*

As the son of Kausalya and Dasharatha, Rama has two arms:

> After offering the wooden shoes before Lord Rāmacandra, Lord Bharata stood with folded hands, His eyes full of tears, and Lord Rāmacandra bathed Bharata with tears **while embracing Him with both arms for a long time**.
> -*Srimad Bhagavatam 9.10.39*

As the son of Devaki and Vasudeva, Krishna is requested to hide his Chaturbhuja form and become and ordinary child:

> O my Lord, You are the all-pervading Supreme Personality of Godhead, and Your transcendental four-armed form, holding conchshell, disc, club and lotus, is unnatural for this world. **Please withdraw this form** [and become just like a natural human child so that I may try to hide You somewhere].
> -*Srimad Bhagavatam 10.3.30*